# 404 error apatche tomcat using jersey and web.xml

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jersey

I think everything is fine with my project but I get 404 error even with a simple project also I'm new to Java EE if anyone can help me I would be so glad.
here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" 
encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>TestRest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>test</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>True</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and here is my Rest class:

```
package test;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/search")
public class Rest {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN + "; charset=utf-8")
    @Path("/hotels/items/")
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("salam");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see the message `salam` on your console or log by accessing to `http://[host]:[port]/[contxt]/rest/search/hotels/items/`?

Comment: no I get 404 error which means nothing is found to show on browser it cant find the path at all @KoheiTAMURA

Comment: If you only created `Rest` class, you will always get 404 error other than accessing to `http://[host]:[port]/[contxt]/rest/search/hotels/items/`.

Comment: Try registering the class named Rest directly instead of setting package scan in web.xml. Have a look at the Jersey servlet configuration at [my blog](http://www.pavel.cool/jee-tips/REST-for-old-JEE/) and ignore rest of the article :)